# How to get Apache web server to run on other computers?

Tags: apache-http-server

I have been using Apache Web Server for a while now and one thing I have noticed is that outside of my computer I can not access it.

I use my Apache server for PHP development on my computer, but I would like to access stuff I have made outside of my computer. I am on a linksys router network. I usually run it of `http://localhost/` or `http://127.0.0.1/`.

I IPCONFIGED my computer and got

192.168.1.105 so I went there with my browser and got the page just fine.

I tried doing this on another computer on the same network but it didn't work.

How do I fix this?

Sorry about the bad wording. I am in ah hurry

Information you might need to know:

Server: Apache 2.2
Operating System: Windows 7 ULTIMATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adelec is correct, you need to setup the port forwarding on your router. In addition, apache needs to be configured to accept requests from remote connections. You modify this setting in the primary apache config file, **httpd.conf**. Look for 'Deny from all' in the file, change it to 'Allow from all' (read the comments in the file, you only want to do this for the main web root).

Comment: Also, if you have a firewall running on your web development computer, you might need to allow Apache to accept incoming connections.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the HTTP port (80) on the server, then if you need to go through an external network, you will have to set the router to forward the HTTP 80 to that server (192.168.1.105)